# contents are going outside from grid box

Tags: html, css

```css
.mn2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30vh 30vh;
  grid-template-rows: 30vh 30vh;
  grid-gap: 5px 5px;
  height: 50vh;
  border: 3px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="mn2">
  <div class="box2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur doloremque labore corrupti atque.
  </div>

  <div class="box3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque error maiores asperiores! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </div>
  <div class="box4">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit
  </div>
  <div class="box5">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sit quaerat error ad, ut nulla.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If would be really helpful, if you would describe your problem in a few short sentences.

Comment: You are setting your rows 30vh & 30vh that equals to 60vh but you set the height of the grid as 50vh. Obviously it will overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should let the content define box height & widths. By setting everything to auto..
you can set height of the boxes with `grid-auto-rows: [first-row-height] [second-row-height];` for eg

`grid-auto-rows: 200px 200px;`

```css
.mn2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-auto-rows: 200px 200px;
  grid-gap: 5px 5px;
  height: auto;
  
}

.mn2>div {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="mn2">
  <div class="box2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur doloremque labore corrupti atque.
  </div>

  <div class="box3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque error maiores asperiores! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </div>
  <div class="box4">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit
  </div>
  <div class="box5">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sit quaerat error ad, ut nulla.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but can I set the height of each box ?

Comment: yes you but use `grid-auto-rows:` for that i have updated the answer with fixed heights

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.mn2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 24% 24% 24% 24%;
  grid-gap: 5px 5px;
  height: auto;
  border: 3px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="mn2">
  <div class="box2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur doloremque labore corrupti atque.
  </div>

  <div class="box3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque error maiores asperiores! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </div>
  <div class="box4">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit
  </div>
  <div class="box5">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sit quaerat error ad, ut nulla.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Let me know if this is what you need

Comment: thanks but I don't want to display contents in one line